# Similar PsExec.exe in TCL

Tags: tcl, psexec

My goal is to launch an application on a remote server from my computer and retrieve information from this application, I have a solution with this microsoft utility [psexec.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec), but I wanted to know if I could do it in pure TCL.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Expect](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/index)?

Comment: @BryanOakley , no I don't know , I’ll try to look at your link...

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do it in pure TCL in general. As a workaround, you can make server service in pure TCL that will listen some tcp port, receive commands and execute them locally. Run it on remote machines and send the needed commands through socket.

Also, you can execute commands on remote machines using WMI. But this requires non-standard tcl modules (tcom or twapi). For example: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Remote+exec+with+tcom+and+WMI You can wrap tcl interpetator, runtime libraries and all the necessary modules to one tclkit executable file and use it to run scripts that access remote machines via WMI. With this option you will have an issue with getting the output from remote commands. But that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: ok , thanks for the link ,Expect should be the solution as I can see , but for this moment , that doesn't work... I think PsExec does the job and I will keep this solution, @Chpock thanks anyway for your contribution